# Get related cousin model in a template

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm struggling finding docs or examples how to get data from a cousin related model.

So if the models look like this:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=550)

class Quantity(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)        
    part = models.ForeignKey('Part', related_name='quantity_part')
    stockarea = models.ForeignKey('StockArea', related_name='quantity_stockarea')

class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=550)

class StockArea(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=550)
    stock = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, related_name='stockarea_stock')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.area
```

And in the view I get the part like this:

```
def details(request, part_id):
    part = get_object_or_404(Part, pk=part_id)
    context = {
        'part': part,
    }
    return render(request, 'part/details.html', context)
```

Finally template trying to display the data:

```
{% for a in part.quantity_part.all %}
   {{ a.quantity }} pcs
   Find part in area: {{ a.stockarea }} 
   in stock: {{ part.stockarea.stock.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

You see how I try to get the name of the stock. I can't figure out how to be able to get hold of the name of the stock. I have a path there from the part.
**Part** have a `related_name` to the **Quantity** model called `quantity_park`. And in the model **Quantity** I have a relation to model **StockArea**. And from there I have a relation to model **Stock**.

Guidance is much appreciated =)

*Maybe I'm totally doing this backwards. Maybe I'm defining the models wrong to begin with. I'm used to MySQL, so this is very new to me.*

Comment: Since stock is a manytomany field in your stockarea model, you need loop through all the stocks in stockarea to get the names of them. Something like this: `{% for stock in a.stockarea.stock.all %} in stock: {{ stock.name }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: @anupsabraham You are right. That's probably pretty dumb of me. One _area_ is of course only related to one _stock_.

Comment: Then it is better to change that field to onetoone or foreignkey.

Answer (score 0):

The data model for this is better done as:

```
from django.db import models


class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField()
    abbrev = models.CharField(max_length=7)


class Warehouse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()

class StockArea(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse)
    # Adjust type of these identifiers as necessary
    aisle = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    shelf = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=550)
    description = models.TextField()

class Stock(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, related_name='stock')  # Adds a 'stock' attribute to 'Part'
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    location = models.ForeignKey(StockArea)
```

View code:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Part

class PartView(generic.DetailView):
    # Pre-fetch related objects. This also illustrates the joins
    queryset = Part.objects.prefetch_related(
        'stock', 'stock__location', 'stock__location__warehouse'
    )
    template_name = 'yourapp/part/detail.html'
```

Template code `yourapp/part/detail.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <h1 class="title">{{ part.name }}</h1>
                <p>{{ part.description }}</p>
                <h2>Stock information</h2>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    {% for stock in part.stock.all %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                Aisle {{ stock.location.aisle }}, shelf {{ stock.location.shelf }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 label">
                                Warehouse:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                {{ stock.location.warehouse.name }}
                                <address>
                                    {{ stock.location.warehouse.address }}
                                </address>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 label">
                                Available:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 numeric">
                                {{ stock.quantity }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-1 unit">
                                {{ stock.unit.abbrev }} <sup><i class="fa fa-icon" title="{{ stock.unit.name }}"></i></sup>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Edit**:

- Fixed model relation for stock/part.
- Adjusted data model conforming specs in comments
- Added view code to illustrate join and point to [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).
- Adjusted template to match changes

Comment: The thing I was focused about is the _StockArea_ which actually is the spot inte warehouse where the part is located. Like _Aisle 2, Bin 5_. But I walso want to be able to get the Stock.name.

Comment: Can an item be at multiple spots in a warehouse? If not, the difference is semantic and you can simply add a char field to stock.

Comment: It can be in multiple spots. Also the spot have characteristics excluded in example, that I excluded so the code didn&#39;t get messy. I have max_volume and max_load for example. So each spot does not get filled more then possible or a shelf brakes because weight. I&#39;m used to SQL. Shouldn&#39;t something like `JOIN` work with this?

Comment: Django joins automatically behind the scenes. I'll add small viewcode so you can see and update models to match specs.